# Is NestJS compatible with es2020 typescript?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, ecmascript-2020

when building a skeleton NestJS app, it sets es2017 in tsconfig. When trying to change it to es2020, it seems to work but hard to say without testing everything. I was unable to find any insights online. Are there any known issues with es2020 typescript and NestJS?

Comment: I've been using `ES2021` as a target of my project with no worries.